Svelte 5 false positive - Cannot find module 'svelte-filepond' or its corresponding type declarations
Stack: Svelte 5 / SvelteKit / Filepond
I'm getting a false positive for a missing Filepond dependency in my SvelteKit app. In a custom svelte component I'm importing Filepond like so:
import FilePond, { registerPlugin } from 'svelte-filepond';


Error: Cannot find module 'svelte-filepond' or its corresponding type declarations

Filepond is showing up in my app and working as expected despite the error warning.
My package.json seems fine:
"dependencies": {
    "filepond": "^4.31.1",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.11",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.12",
    "svelte-filepond": "^0.2.2",
}

tsconfig:
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "bundler"
    },
}

vite.config:
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});

svelte.config:
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;

Things I've tried:

delete node_modules & .svelte-kit folders & reload
run npm check
run npm build

EDIT: I've added // @ts-ignore as a temporary workaround for the time being

did you ever find a solution?

I think it's more a typescript issue, since you use strict mode.
You can try to add declare module 'svelte-filepond'; in a ts description file (app.d.ts for example)

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue
